# How do I show a specific badge for woocommerce 'Coming Soon' products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm able to display certain badges for woocommerce products that are either 'sold out', or 'new', but I want to be able to show a third category - 'coming soon'

my code so far is below. I'm trying to target products that are both 'out of stock' AND category 'coming-soon'.

Is there a way to show a product that is 'out of stock' and NOT 'coming soon'? I dont think this is correct - I'm not a coder lol: *!is_product_category*

```
    // Add WooCommerce Sold Out Badge Storewide
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && !is_product_category( 'coming-soon' )  ) {
    echo '<span class="now_sold">Sold Out</span>';
       }
    });
    // Add WooCommerce Sold Out Badge for a Single Product
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', function() {
       global $product;
         if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && !is_product_category( 'coming-soon' )  ) {
           echo '<span class="now_sold">Sold Out</span>';
       }
    });
    // Add WooCommerce New Badge Storewide
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
       global $product;
       if ( $product->is_featured() ) {
           echo '<span class="new">New</span>';
       }
    });
    // Add WooCommerce New Badge for a Single Product
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', function() {
       global $product;
       if ( $product->is_featured() ) {
           echo '<span class="new">New</span>';
       }
    });
    
    // Add WooCommerce Coming Soon Badge Storewide
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
       global $product;
         if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && is_product_category( 'coming-soon' )  ) {
           echo '<span class="now_sold">Coming Soon</span>';
       }
    });

    // Add WooCommerce Coming Soon Badge for a Single Product
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', function() {
       global $product;
        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && is_product_category( 'coming-soon' )  ) {
   echo '<span class="now_sold">Coming Soon</span>';
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that worked:

```
 // Add WooCommerce New Badge Storewide
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function () {
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_featured()) {
        echo '<span class="new">New</span>';
    } elseif (!$product->is_in_stock() && !has_term('coming-soon', 'product_cat')) {
        echo '<span class="now_sold">Sold Out</span>';
    } elseif (!$product->is_in_stock() && has_term('coming-soon', 
'product_cat')) {
        echo '<span class="coming-soon">Coming Soon!</span>';
    }
});

// Add WooCommerce New Badge for a Single Product
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {

if ( $product->is_featured() && !has_term( 'coming-soon', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    $availability['availability'] = __('NEW PRODUCT!', 'woocommerce' );
}
elseif ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && !has_term( 'coming-soon', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce' );
}
elseif ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && has_term( 'coming-soon', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    $availability['availability'] = __('Coming Soon', 'woocommerce' );
}    
return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and remove unnecessary code . You don't need to call same hook's twice .

You may use [has_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) instead of [is_product_category](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

```php
// Add WooCommerce New Badge Storewide
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function () {
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_featured()) {
        echo '<span class="new">New</span>';
    } elseif (!$product->is_in_stock() && !has_term('coming-soon', 'product_cat')) {
        echo '<span class="now_sold">Sold Out</span>';
    } elseif (!$product->is_in_stock() && has_term('coming-soon', 'product_cat')) {
        echo '<span class="now_sold">Coming Soon</span>';
    }
});

// Add WooCommerce New Badge for a Single Product
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', function () {
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_featured()) {
        echo '<span class="new">New</span>';
    } elseif (!$product->is_in_stock() && has_term('coming-soon', 'product_cat')) {
        echo '<span class="now_sold">Coming Soon</span>';
    } elseif (!$product->is_in_stock() && !has_term('coming-soon', 'product_cat')) {
        echo '<span class="now_sold">Sold Out</span>';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  Actually it works for storewide (archive), but for individual, it still shows out of stock even if 'coming soon' category is checked...

Comment: `has_term('coming-soon', 'product_cat')` here 1st parameter is your category slug . go to your edit category page , copy slug and replace `has_term('REPLACE_HERE', 'product_cat')` here .

Comment: thx. Still no luck with single. Should work but won't. I'm using Beaver Themer fyi. Maybe that's issue.

Comment: here's site: https://graphics3stage.wpengine.com/product-category/pop-up-business-personalized-christmas-cards/    I have one product set to new, one as coming soon, one as sold out. They work perfectly in archive, just not single... :(

Comment: UPDATE: I copied some code I had found earlier that was only working for the SINGLE product. Got it working!